# What do fromXScale and fromYScale mean in Android animations?

Tags: android, android-animation

These terms come in picture when we use animations in android but what exactly do they mean in the context of Android animations?

Comment: animation start scaling. E. g. scal from 0.5x size to 2x size

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko  is it about the size of the view on which we perform animations??

Comment: yes , exactly .

Answer (score 0):

**link** https://www.journaldev.com/9481/android-animation-example

this site explain about ,

**Android Animation**
Animation in android apps is the process of creating motion and shape change. The basic ways of animation that we’ll look upon in this tutorial are:

- Fade In Animation
- Fade Out Animation
- Cross Fading Animation
- Blink Animation
- Zoom In Animation
- Zoom Out Animation
- Rotate Animation Move Animation
- Slide Up Animation
- Slide Down Animation
- Bounce Animation
- Sequential Animation
- Together Animation

Comment: they have used it in few animation XML's but haven't mentioned anywhere what is it for but thanks for the quick response.